# Does SOSL allow the `-` dash character?

Tags: sosl

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm?search_text=escaping) you need to escape the following special characters in SOSL search text.

> Escaping special characters `& | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ “ ~ * ? : \ '`

The `-` dash character is not in that list, yet when I attempt SOSL with the `-` dash character in the search text I get the following error:

> line 1:14 mismatched character '-' expecting '}'

A sample SOSL that returns the error is:

```
FIND {some-email@gmail.com} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Lead, Contact
```

When I escape the `-` dash character the SOSL query works just fine.

```
FIND {some\-email@gmail.com} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Lead, Contact
```

Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug in Salesforce, or is the documentation incomplete?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure why that part of the documentation is not mentioning `-` and `+` characters, but they are reserved according to this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm):

> **Reserved Characters**
>
> The following characters are reserved: 
>   `? & | ! { } [ ] ( ) ^ ~ * : \ " ' + -`
>
> Reserved characters, if specified in a text search, must be escaped (preceded by the backslash \ character) in order to be properly interpreted. An error occurs if you do not precede reserved characters with a backslash. This is true even if the SearchQuery is enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: It appears your documentation is better than mine.